# Why is tetraamminecopper(II) a square planar and not a tetrahedral species?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, molecular-structure

In $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4]^2+}$, the $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ion has 9 electrons in the $\mathrm{3d}$ orbital with only one unpaired electron. How is it a square planar geometry? Where is that unpaired electron going?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is very convenient to use crystal field theory to discuss this.

It is usually assumed that in octahedral coordination the energy levels of the five d-orbitals are split, with two orbitals ($d_{z^2}$ and $d_{x^2-y^2}$) well above the other three. The splitting is assumed to be large enough to overcome electron pairing energy.

The first six electrons will populate three lower orbitals ($d_{xy}$, $d_{xz}$, $d_{yz}$). The next two electrons should occupy $d_{z^2}$ and $d_{x^2-y^2}$. However, if these two electrons occupy $d_{z^2}$, two corresponding opposite ligands become well shielded and leave. This is the common case of $d^8$ complexes, such as $\ce{Ni^{+2}}$, $\ce{Pd^{+2}}$, $\ce{Pt^{+2}}$, $\ce{Rh^{+1}}$, $\ce{Cu^{+3}}$ etc.

Adding one more electron makes the remaining ligand's bonding weaker. The charge of bivalent cation $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ is large enough to bond four charged ligands if available, such as in $\ce{[CuCl4]^{2-}}$, but the ligands are bound weakly and easily dissociate.

However, $\ce{Cu^{+2}}$ ions usually adopt a distorted octahedral geometry, with two ligands having a longer bond length than the four others. These two are very weakly bound and exchange quickly. For this reason the $\ce{NH3}$ complex is written with only four molecules; the two other are so weakly bound.

This type of distortion is a case of [Jahn–Teller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect) distortion, very common in chemistry.

Comment: Why should we use octahedral splitting system if its a square planar species ?

Comment: @DhrubaBanerjee square planar species usually have enough place for two extra ligands. We *do* need to understand why it does not accept these ligands if available, so we have to consider octahedral splitting as well.  It helps to draw the d-orbitals in octahedral splitting to understand why $d^8$ often (but not alwasy) square planar.

Comment: Where does that unpaired lone electron get accomodated in such case ?

Comment: @DhrubaBanerjee $d_{z^2}$ orbital, which in square planar species is perpendicular to the ligand sqare. In $\ce{Cu^{+2}}$  $d_{z^2}$ contains two electrons and also is perpendicular to square of strongly bound ligands, while $d_{x^2-y^2}$ with one electrons positioned near ligands. Other three $d$-orbitals occupied by two electrons each are positioned either between ligands ($d_{xy}$) or are perpendicular to the square ($d_{xz}$, $d_{ys}$)

Comment: @permeakra Okay, but where did that **unpaired electron** go? Because, if it remained in the $d_{x^2-y^2}$ orbital, then the ion would be $sp^3$ hybridised, but it is not. What is happening here?

Comment: @AritraDas | the ion would be sp3 hybridised | Why so? Forget about hybridization when talking about 3d metal complexes, they are guarded by d-shells and ion radii.

Comment: Since you are describing bonding in your answer, you are actually using [ligand field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_field_theory) as opposed to the older and a bit incomplete crystal field theory.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Is it true that the unpaired electron in d-orbital of Cu is promoted to 4-p orbital for greater stability by involvement of d-orbital in bonding?

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is that $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4]^2+}$ does not exist; the compound you are observing is $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^2+}$. It is not square planar but a Jahn-Teller distorted octahedron. You can check out its structure in the image below.

[image: tetraammin diaqua copper(II)]

You can fill electrons into the energy diagram in a standard fashion. You will arrive at the $\mathrm{d}_{x^2-y^2}$ orbital for the unpaired electron — the one pointing towards the four ammine ligands.

Note that other copper(II) complexes may well be tetrahedral, as is the case for $\ce{[CuCl4]^2-}$. A combination of large ligand size around a small central metal and too much negative charge for a small species causes the tetrahedric structure to be preferred over $\ce{[CuCl6]^4-}$.

Comment: This is quite interesting. Can you tell me the source by any chance? Because I need to use this piece of information for a write-up.

Answer (score -1):

All Cupric complexes irrespective of the kind of ligands is always dsp2 square planar hybridization . Now the question is that why this is so? 
In tetrahedral complexes when Cu is in +2 state the one electron from 4s2 and one from 3d orbital gets removed and so it a 3d9 complex .Now from 3d9 complex one electron goes to 4p orbital and in this way it now becomes 3d8 and dsp2 complex.

Comment: Promotion from $3d$ to $4d$?  Huh?

Comment: Just don’t use hybridisation for transition metal complexes; it does more harm than good.

Comment: I have edited my answer and its 4p instead of 4d.

Comment: Hybridisation theory for TM complexes is questionable at best. I will retract my downvote, but I really cannot recommend using hybridisation.